# Find Available wifi network using ios platform without using Private Framework? (Answer included in it)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, wifi

I found lots of link regarding "All Available WIFI Connection ( not talking only connected WIFI ) " , finally concludes Developer only allows to fetch **CONNECTED WIFI NETWORK** .

HERE IS FEW FACTS WHICH I FOUND DURING RND MAY HELP OTHER ALSO :

```
APPLE introduces MobileWIFI.Framework (private FRAMEWORK ) TO fetch
all available WIFI but it is only works on Jail-Break devices , if
any application use this framework then it would be rejected .
(Mobilewifi.framework allow developer to check how one can populate
wifi list in ios )

MobileWIFI framework is the replacement of existing private
framework.

I found there were few apps earliar which uses private framework to
populate wifi (all available wifi list) and also goes on live but
now they all have been removed .

Even One can not show all nearby device which uses wifi (only
possible through private API) and we can't use it in our
application.
```

So , I request to all member to provide suggestion on this .Also if there be any way we can implement such concept in our application . (as far as RND concern it seems  it is not possible in current version of iOS but hope in the next coming version develper have flexibility to do all this stuff.)

one more thing , how iPhone device list all available WIFI network, it means it uses internally private API but not open for Developer .
Plz correct me if wrong.

Kindly do suggestion .

Comment: There is no way to get list of all wifi available in device, without private app and hacking. Recently I have requested this kind of app to app- store, and app has been rejected. You can get details of only connected wi-fi.

Comment: Exactly it is not possible without using PRIVATE API .

Comment: IT IS POSSIBLE. You need to request Apple to register your app as `HotspotHelper`. Once done, you can use the  `HotspotHelper` framework which allows you to scan Wifis around, get their details and even set the password programatically. BUT it's not as nice as it looks... You can only get the list of Wifis when the user scans them from the device's settings. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31555640/how-to-get-wifi-ssid-in-ios9-after-captivenetwork-is-depracted-and-calls-for-wif/31590787#31590787