# Can we get the wifi name in the ios simulator

Tags: ios, wifi

I can get the wifi name from a real device, but in the simulator it is not giving any value.  Is it possible to get the wifi name in the simulator? Is there any options to get the default wifi name like location services?

Below is my code to get the wifi name on the real device

```
- (NSDictionary *)fetchSSIDInfo
{
    NSArray *interfaceNames = CFBridgingRelease(CNCopySupportedInterfaces());
    NSLog(@"%s: Supported interfaces: %@", __func__, interfaceNames);

    NSDictionary *SSIDInfo;
    for (NSString *interfaceName in interfaceNames) {
        SSIDInfo = CFBridgingRelease(
                                     CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo((__bridge CFStringRef)interfaceName));
        NSLog(@"%s: %@ => %@", __func__, interfaceName, SSIDInfo);

        BOOL isNotEmpty = (SSIDInfo.count > 0);
        if (isNotEmpty) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return SSIDInfo;
}
```

Comment: No, you won't get SSID Info when it is with simulator.

Comment: is there is any options to give a default wifi name & get that name,like the location service ,in the location we can set some manual location like that any option avilable?

Comment: I guess no because in simulator we don't have any (settings) wifi kind.

Comment: in simulator setting-> Developer->wifi is avilable

Comment: What do you get if you use `NetworkExtension` instead? http://stackoverflow.com/a/31590787/78496

Comment: @chedabob ok thanks how can i get list of wifi available without using private APIs

Comment: You don't need to use private API for your method or the one I've linked

Comment: this one i'm getting only the connected connected wifi only